# Splitting individual sound to play in individual speakers

Tags: audio

I just want to point out that I'm a complete novice and have no prior experience with audio so please be patient with me.
Ok, so here goes. I'm a uni student working on a project with sound and vibration. My aim for the end result is (if i can explain it well enough) to have a set up of around 8-10 individual speakers connected together to my mac.

From there i want to deconstruct audio files/music into individual tones and sync these tones to specific speakers: tone 1 to play from speaker 1, tone 2 to play from speaker 2 and so on.
To clarify i want each tone to play separately on an individual speaker.
Is this possible or am i barking up a very complicated/impossible tree? Thanks in advance for any help or guidance anyone can provide.

Comment: Note that "deconstructing" existing music by anything other than simple frequency (e.g. bass/treble) is not a simple project.

Comment: "Deconstructing" is a nice fantasy, not simple at all.

Answer (score 0):

trying not to reference the other answers by saying that it could be done without the use of multi channel audio, IF, you were so inclined to create an external device (after the computer, before the speakers)

this device would need to be some sort of splitter/amplifier/multiband crossover, which you could run as a passive 8 way splitter followed by 8 amplifier circuits with fancy 24db/octave filters.

OR, maybe more easily one larger amplifier circuit FIRST, THEN a passive 8 way splitter and a passive network of resistors capacitors and inductors!

these would be fun builds and probably get you a good grade in a novice electronics lab, but in your application may not be entirely worth the time. still, a more fun and oldschool approach to your problem imho.

Answer (score -1):

By default, multichannel sound files are played with each channel going to one speaker. So just playing an eight-channel file through a 7.1 sound device will do what you want.

Comment: This assumes that the source is recorded as multi channel, which does not seem to be the case here.